# Problemas con clases dentro de clases, mostrar por pantalla

Tags: c#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        vaso A= new vaso(1);
        A.Mezclar();
        A.GetVasoStatus();
    }
    class dado{
            Random rand=new Random();
            int valor=0;
            public void Cambio(){
                valor=rand.Next(0,6);
            }
            public int GetValor(){
                return valor;
            }
        }
    //clase dado finalizada
    class vaso{
        dado[] TotalDados=new dado[cant];//arreglo de dados
        static int cant;
        public vaso(int x){
            cant=x;
        }
        //contructor finalizado

        public void Mezclar(){
            foreach (dado i in this.TotalDados) {
                    i.Cambio();
                }
        }
        //Mezclar finalizado

        public void GetVasoStatus(){
            foreach(dado i in this.TotalDados){
                Console.WriteLine(i.GetValor());
            }
        }
        //GetVasoStatus Finalizado
    }
    //clase vaso finalizada
}
```

*La intencion del porgrama es crear un "vaso" que contenga X dados, seran guardados en un array, los dados solo pueden cambiar de cara y mostrar su valor, mientras que el vaso permite "mezclar" todos los dados dentro. No logro hace que el programa muestre en pantalla al llamar desde main, no se que lo esta causando, no hay ningun tipo de error de ejecucion, parece ser un problema con el arreglo, estoy empezando a jugar un poco con las clases y soy algo novato.*

Comment: Si haces un debug puedes ver el foreach como funciona.

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy en un compilador web, no tengo muchas herramientas, sin embargo, inenté imprimir la casilla 0 del array antes del foreach, y me lanza System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Agrega un punto de interrupción en el foreach y en Visual Studio presiona f5

Answer (score 1):

Solución: Se instanciaba el vector en si pero no cada objeto dentro de el, por lo tanto, cada casilla era nula, la solucion era:

```
        Dado[] TotalDados;//arreglo de dados
        static int cant=1;
        public Vaso(int x){
            TotalDados=new Dado[x];
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i<x;i++)
                TotalDados[i]=new Dado(rand);
        }
```